# Windows Mobile emulator and OpenGL ES

Tags: windows-mobile, opengl-es, emulation

I have a Windows Mobile 5 application that uses OpenGL ES 1.1. It works on Windows Mobile phones (5, 6 and 6.1), but I can't seem to get it working in the emulator.

I've tried downloading [Vincent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogl-es) (SW OpenGL ES library) and placing its DLL with my application, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The problem only happens when I try to use GL. There is no problem running "regular" code on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Pocket PC WM 5.0 MSFP emulator and the *Pidion 5000* device, with Windows Mobile 6.0.

The Pidion executes ARMV4I code but the emulator can't run code that is compiled for ARMV4I processors, but it will run ARMV4 code.

Comment: I'm actually running ARMv5TE code, but that isn't the problem. Apps that don't use GL ES run fine on the emulator.

Comment: Oh, ok. If you don't built that code then you should check which processors your emulator supports. Are you sure that the emulator has no problem running *their binary* machine code?